# A button that makes a redirect

Tags: html, wordpress, redirect

I'm pretty new to this and I have a question, is there any way to create a code that can be posted to all the pages of a website that makes some kind of a button that redirects mywebsite.com/tilte to mysecondwebsite.com/title

I practically want to create a button for every page that redirects to another website with the same url but different domain.

(I want to use it for a wordpress website)

Comment: why you need to put that on each page? why don't you put it on header. 

Show some code what you have done so that you'll get help on it. asking questions like this will not be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own simple plugin which registers a widget and put this in a sidebar. Than you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to retrieve the URL without the host but including query variables.